# Find angle to rotate multiple extrusion. (geo node)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to rotate an extrude face to create a tree like structure, this so far is working for extrusion. But rotation is off (see branches on picture), result should be an equal rotation on each extrusions, I am not sure how to solve that issue.I have been trying to use normal, but i think it is the wrong aproach.
I'm using blender 4.0 (beta) with repeat zone but i don't think problem is related to that.
Here is the .blend (you need blender beta4.0) [source file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v0qd0YqDXKR938RfvMqrgMsAGj05EYf4/view)
Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

[image]

to explain a bit better the issue i have see in red the wrong result below.

[image]

Comment: r u expecting this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0K44.png

Comment: Hi thanks for looking at that, not really, I'm looking at creating a tree like structure, so for that i need to be able to get extrusion to point up following the current branch
a bit like in this picture but in 3d https://www.101computing.net/wp/wp-content/uploads/recursive-tree-1.png 
In the actual geo node setup the angle is not constant for each branch, it might be related to gimbal lock problem with angle, but couldn't sort it out.

Comment: " rotate a extrude face based on normal of its extrusion origin" - extruded face has the same normal as its origin, no? So just rotate around self's normal. If it's e.g. 2nd rotation, and normal changes, than before first rotation capture the normal…

Comment: sorry i explained badly, i edited my post and title, also i think using normal is the wrong aproach, after visualizing them, i can see that i can't really use them to find rotation. But probably need to compute the rotation an other way.

Comment: You want to 'maintain' a direction of growth. So after extruding, you want to capture the normal of the base, onto the SIDE faces. Then when extruding, you want to use a cross product of growth direction, with base normal, and the result is an axis of rotation, using which you want to rotate towards either the growth direction, or just up...

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady i have been trying for a couple of hours with no luck, i'm not sure what you mean by capturing the normal of the base onto the  side face, would i need to use a first capture attribute on the base, connected to a second one on the side?

Comment: try rotating the `offset` [the input to the extrud node] and not the mesh afterwards.  this will simplify your setup and hopefully fix your issue. use the `normal ` node as the offset but rotate it first. there is no need for s center in this case because it's a direction (not a position) and is always centered.

Comment: or if you are anyway using `Align Euler to Vector` just use the vector as the offset.

Comment: oh sorry I think I misunderstood your question. I propose using axis angles. they are easier to get right without the weird issues from gimbal lock and euler interpolation.  if you use Eulers then you might not be able to use the factor of the Align Euler to Vector (interpolation isn't **so** viable for Eulers). anyway axis angle are much better and I've even found they are better than quaternions (at least for this).

Comment: the only thing is you need to implement a different "Align euler to vector" which aligns vectors to axis angles. luckily for you I did that already https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/291020/165102