How to align a vector to a specific axis

In Geometry Nodes, I want to align a specified vector to a custom axis. Since I have no knowledge of matrix transformations, I really don't know where to start. Could you please help me? Thank you.

Is your question any different from https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/290606/geometry-nodes-aligning-one-vector-to-another ? If yes, could you explain in what way ?

Thank you, I found the answer.


First, project onto the plane perpendicular to the axis, then calculate the angle between the two vectors and determine the direction through the cross product, deciding whether to reverse the angle. This ensures that after rotating the vector, it aligns with the target vector along the axis.
